# MCUs programmable by USB or ethernet

Tags: microcontroller, programming, programmer, in-circuit

The NXP LPC1342 microcontrollers have a built-in bootloader which allows programming the device via usb: The bootloader is triggered by pulling one pin to GND on bootup. The microcontroller then enumerates as a USB mass storage device onto which the firmware file can be copied without any additional hardware or drivers with most operating systems.

Apparently there are other devices which have unusual methods of in system programming (i.e. not via a classic serial interfaces SPI, JTAG, SWD, etc).

**Does anybody know other examples of devices programmable from factory in system by USB, ethernet or similar?**

Answer (score 3):

Atmel's AVR chips with USB (at90usb1287, atmega32u4, atmega8u2, atxmega, etc) come factory-programmed with a USB DFU bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

According to this document: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu134n/spmu134n.pdf, TI Stellaris series microcontrollers can be updated through serial, usb, can or ethernet.

OR You can write Your own bootloader, which is not so hard to do.

Comment: As far as I see this is the documentation of a TI bootloader that users can program into their devices. I cannot find anything that states that devices come preprogrammed from factory with it. Maybe I missed it?

Comment: Never mind, looking through some datasheets it is clear that the Stellaris series comes with preprogrammed bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Also preprogrammed with very versatile bootloader is the STMicroelectronics STM32 series.